# Caching data from database using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

When using JDBC to retrieve query results I use ResultSet like:
`ResultSet result_set = statement.executeQuery(query);`
In documentation it says: "A ResultSet object maintains a cursor pointing to its current row of data." meaning that if I do `result_set.close()` before I parse the query results I loose them. If I parse data in ResultSet right away I'am maintaining connection to the database during parsing process. I want to minimize time, I want to parse query result without being connected to the DB.

Is there a way to store query data in such way that I can close connection to the database before I parse the results?

for example something like this:

```java
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet result_set = statement.executeQuery(query);
// store data retrieved from query
result_set.close();
statement.close();
connection.close();
// do something with stored data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `RowSet`

The [`javax.sql.rowset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.sql.rowset/javax/sql/rowset/package-summary.html) package extends `ResultSet`, adding various features.

In particular, [`CachedRowSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.sql.rowset/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html) copies the rows’ data into memory. To quote the documentation:

> A `CachedRowSet` object is a container for rows of data that caches its rows in memory, which makes it possible to operate without always being connected to its data source.
>
> …
>
> A `CachedRowSet` object is a disconnected rowset, which means that it makes use of a connection to its data source only briefly.

The trick is finding a capable concrete implementation of the interface. Oracle provides an open-source reference implementation from the days of Sun. But, as I recall (and I may be wrong), that implementation had some limitations or flaws that went unaddressed. Be sure to test thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

To fill the blanks in your snippet with a minimalistic approach:

```
    final var rowLength =
            result_set
                .getMetaData()
                .getColumnCount();

    final var resultCache = Stream.<Object[]>builder();

    while ( result_set.next() )
    {
        final var row = new Object[ rowLength ];
        for ( int index=1; index<=rowLength; index++ )
        {
            row[index] = result_set.getObject( index );
        }
        
        resultCache.accept( row );
    }

    record MyData( Integer value, String text )
    {
        // ... transformation could be placed in here with alternative constructor
    }
        
    final var results =
            resultCache.build()
                    .map( row -> new MyData( (Integer) row[0],
                                             (String)  row[1] ) )
                    .toList();
```

This assumes you know the ordering in the returned data and the types to do the 'parsing' / etc later on.
Thinking about the computationtime needed for the 'parsing' and the memoryfootprint and so on is a good way to become familiar with the behavior of the framework. I recommend trying out diffent sizes of resultsets (in number and rows) and the complexity of the parsing/ transformation. Maybe a look at a jpa-implementation helps to understand the possible solutions.

In this post more details regarding result-extraction can be found: [How to fetch entire row as array of objects with JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11826814/9991282)

Answer (score 0):

## `record`

[Java 16](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_16) gained the important new feature of [records](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395).

When the main purpose of your class is to communicate data transparently and immutably, define that class as a `record`.

A record is brief. At a minimum, you merely declare the name and type of each member field. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

```
record Person ( long id , String name ) {}
```

Conveniently, a record can be declared locally, within a method, as an alternative to declaring nested within a class or as a separate class. (Ditto for enums and interfaces now!)

So as part of your JDBC code, you can define a `record` with fields to match the raw data of your rows returned by your `ResultSet`. Quickly loop the rows, passing the fields of the database row to the constructor of the Java `record`.

Then close your `ResultSet`, to free up resources on the database server. Proceed with the work of processing the data of those Java `record` objects that now cache the data in memory of your [JVM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine).

In this example code, we use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax to automatically close the `ResultSet` object. Then we move on to process the data cached in `record` objects.

```java
List < Person > persons = new ArrayList<>() ;
try (
    ResultSet resultSet = … ;  // A resource to be automatically closed.
){
    while( rs.next() ) 
    {
        long id = resultSet.getLong( "id_" );
        String name = resultSet.getString( "name_" );
        Person person = new Person( id , name ) ;
        persons.add( person ) ;
    }
}  
// The `ResultSet` is implicitly closed by exiting the try-with-resources.
this.processPersons( persons ) ;
```